# How to shim a dependency in babel.config.js in react-native?

Tags: react-native, babeljs, shim, babel-plugin-module-resolver

I've got a dependency I'd like to shim on my react-native project. I currently have the following code on my `babel.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      
    ],
  };
};
```

I've found the extension `babel-plugin-module-resolver` which seems to be helpful (any other alternative would work too) and tried to follow [their examples](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver) but they didn't work

I've tried the following:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      [
        'module-resolver',
        {
          root: ["./src"],
          alias: {
            '@dependency/to-shim': 'path/to-shimmer',
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};
```

but that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error.
The code when running works correctly.
The problem is with build. The path still absolute.

`babel.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['.'],
        alias: {
          '@services': './src/services',
        },
      },
    ],
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
  ],
};
```

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@services*": ["./src/services"]
    },
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "error",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitUseStrict": false,
    "noStrictGenericChecks": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "target": "esnext"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "commitlint.config.js",
    "metro.config.js",
    "jest.config.js",
    "babel.config.js"
  ]
}
```

[screenshot - should be relative after build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnnPf.png)